# .env vs config.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started learning `JavaScript` / `node.js` (a gentle introduction to back-end webdev), and thus I am completely green in the subject.

A few days ago I was reading a tutorial from which I learned to keep my confidential data (like passwords) in a `config.json` file.

Today I have discovered (by a chance) `.env` file, and the more I learn about it, it seems, the more people are using it to actually store passwords.

So when should I use `.env` and when should I use `config.json`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## The Question

When should `.env` be used over `config.json` and for what?

## The answer

This is a rather difficult answer. On the one hand, you should only really ever use either of these tools while in development. This means that when in a production or prod-like environment, you would add these variables directly to the environment:

```
NODE_ENV=development node ./sample.js --mongodb:host "dharma.mongohq.com" --mongodb:port 10065
```

There is no real clear winner over the other per se as they are both helpful in different ways. You can have nested data with `config.json`, but on the other hand, you can also have a cleaner data structure with `.env`

Some thing also to note is that you never want to commit these files to source control (git, svc etc).

On the other hand, these tools make it very easy for beginners to get started quickly without having to worry about how to set the environment variables and the differences between a windows environment and a linux one.

All in all, I'd say its really up to the developer.

Comment: Is there any performace differance? At a first glance, a `.env` needs a node package to be read, but json doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Movahhedi good question - I believe your assessment is correct; but running some tests myself, and seems like the difference is negligible really to performance (I tested on our prod application which is about a million lines of code)

Comment: I'm asking myself the performance tradeoff as well, but all those costs are build-time costs and the total lines of javascript being added to read these files seems negligible in terms of user-facing performance and overall build time performance.

Answer (score 28):

`.env` files are generally used to store information related to the particular deployment environment, while `config.json` files might be used to store data particular to the application as a whole.

either approach works, and whether or not your config files are stored in your repository is more a function of whether the data needs to be confidential.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what this might look like?

Answer (score 11):

This largely comes down to personal preference and the conventions of the frameworks you're using. They're just different formats for storing the same kind of information.

Some example config file formats:

- `.env`
- `*.yml` (YAML files)
- `*.ini` (normally Windows-only)
- `*.json`

At the end of the day, they all accomplish the same purpose: providing your application with environment-specific information (credentials, file paths, connection strings, etc.). Choose the format which best fits your choice of framework.

Answer (score 11):

I think it's really up to you, the important thing to remember is why you're using this approach. The idea is to save your sensitive data in a file that doesn't get pushed to source control or any other place other than your local environment - this keeps the data safer. Then when you're ready to deploy to a remote server somewhere, you need to manually insert those values into that environment.

I generally use `.env` because the syntax for getting data from a `.env` file is supported in many remote environments - like heroku. When I deploy an app to heroku, I can go into the settings of the app and put in the environment variables using the heroku dashboard UI - I don't have to figure out how to get a json file manually created, etc... (maybe there are other workarounds). After the variables are in place, I just use `process.env.variableName` to access the data.

Comment: In addition, many of these remote environments provide command line utilities to add .env file to such environments.

Answer (score 9):

**[Statistically comparing the two NPM packages](https://www.npmtrends.com/config-vs-dotenv-vs-nconf-vs-rc)** (along with other similar solutions) might be the best way to decide for yourself.

At the time of this writing, **[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)** is a much smaller package with greater support (actual contributors aside, only deduced by the number of remaining issues and immense popularity).  It's also newer by 2.5 years and, if fanfare is important to you, has twice as many stars.

[image]

Comment: most people don't use the config package, rather just load it in directory using require or fs with json parse

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting deployment of your application in Docker, then `.env` is 100% the way to go. The ability to use nested data in `config.json` is great, but you'll be looking at some PITA when you need to migrate that data to a `.env` to make deployment with Docker work. `docker build` and `docker-compose` both are designed to use `.env` natively, so if you start with that then it will facilitate a smooth path to "Dockerizing" your application.

I am currently porting an application to run in Docker which was written with no such forethought, and it is quite painful... lots of refactoring, and ***only*** for the nested stuff. The basic `key:value` properties are easy to migrate to a `.env`:

```
~$ cat config.json
{
  "PROTOCOL": "https",
  "HOST": "example.com",
  "PORT": 443
}
...
```

```
~$ cat .env
PROTOCOL="https"
HOST="example.com"
PORT=443
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer json because typescript can infer type from it, this is not possible with env file